# Read multiple datagrams from network queue

Tags: c++, networking, boost, udp, boost-asio

I'm transferring datagrams from one point to another by using Boost ASIO with UDP.

- My sender sends a datagram every 500 milliseconds
- My receiver listens for incoming data and then works with it. The receiver uses [async_receive_from](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_receive_from/overload1.html) to receive data

In certain cases it could be possible that the receiver needs more than 500 milliseconds to work with the data. The sender does not stop sending data.

**Current Behaviour:**
The sent datagrams are queued in the operating systems network queue. When I perform a `async_receive_from`, I get the next UDP datagrams to work with.

**Wanted Behaviour:**
The sent datagrams are queued in the operating systems network queue. When I perform a receive, I get all the datagrams. The queue is empty then. I do not know how many datagrams are in the queue, neither do I know the size of them.

Is it possible to achieve something like this preferably with Boost::ASIO and `async_receive_from`? If not: Are there other libraries which could do something like this?

If another solution is provided: I'm working on Linux and Windows, would be cool if your solution is portable.

Comment: IMHO a solution is not to rely on some "operating systems network queue", but organize such queue inside of the receiver. The logic is that there are two threads - the 1st one receives packets and stores them to the queue and the 2nd one takes the queued packets and handles them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why didn't you create an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Because, I think, it does not give a direct answer to your question. It is only a suggestion. The answer should be - yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use multiple threads, if possible. The following is a similar piece of code that I made, that is similar in nature to what you want.

```
void Session::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    static int count = 0;
    std::cout << "reading..." << std::endl;
    //std::string sClientIp = socket().remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
    if (!error)
    {
        // This is one place where you can put your thread call.
        try
        {
            // Will have async_read_some reading on the socket and call handle_read when something is transfered
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(dataRx, max_length),
                boost::bind(&Session::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        catch(std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Read some failed: " << e  << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if(error == boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        std::cout << "There was an error in handle_read" << std::endl;
        delete this;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "some error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Inside of handle_read, you will want a way to create a thread with the processed data, which will run independently of the main thread. If there is any confusion in how this is handled, let me know.

Comment: Thought I could get around it without having to integrate threads, but it seems to be the best solution. Implemented a solution this morning which works. Thanks for your code.

Comment: @MOnsDaR, probably is possible to avoid additional threads by using coroutines. The [HTTP Server 4 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.http_server_4) demonstrates this way.